# Styling messed up when page is open in new tab

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

I have a login form that opens in a fancybox. My problem is that when the user just clicks on the link nothing wrong happens, but when he opens it in a new tab, the style is messed up, because the page is designed to be minimal (only login form with forgot password link).

How can I make the link on fancybox, not the same as when opened in a new tab?
Can I detect it in PHP (server side)?
Or can I set fancybox to open a different location on clicking on the link ?

Comment: thx and sorry i couldn't think of a title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you pass a variable to the login window when the user clicks normally that indicates the page was loaded normally and then server side you decide which CSS to load based on the presence of the variable. That way you can accommodate both cases.